# How to array data load into input in JavaScrript?

Tags: javascript

I want to load `fileArray` data as value into  `name="article_media"` input. but i don't understand how to insert this array data into input.

I don't understand how to insert array data into `input(multiple files)`

```html
<input class="form-control" hidden aria-hidden="true" type="file" name="article_media" 
id="id_article_media" multiple accept>

<script>
    let oldArray = [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "vue-file-agent.umd.js",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "dribbble.webp",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Screenshot from 2022-06-23 08-25-07.png",
        }
    ]

    const articleMedia = document.querySelector('#id_article_media');
    articleMedia.value = oldArray;
    console.log(articleMedia.value)
</script>
```

Comment: File input values are read-only.

Comment: The better question is WHY are you trying to pre populate file inputs? That would be a security risk for browsers to allow that feature.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because JavaScript file inputs are read only for security reasons.  This question is a non-starter, as it is impossible to solve in the manner OP wishes to do.